# How to sort a date range column with time range in a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, mvp

I have a table with a column named as "Absence Date" with values like this ->
07/13/2015- 07/16/2015
  9:00 am - 5 pm
How can I sort this table based on this column ? any help through jquery?

Comment: What is the data type of column ? What database you are using ? SQL Server ? If the data type is `varchar`, and the example of value (`07/13/2015- 07/16/2015 9:00 am - 5 pm`) you gave a single value, then you should think to normalize the table by using two date type columns.

Comment: Is this a gridview or an html table?

Comment: @Brij its a table with varchar and we cant normalize it as it is working in production like that and the business dosent wants like that!